# How to upload a file present in S3 from AWS EMR to EC2 machine using java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sftp, amazon-emr

Is there any way to upload a file which is stored on AWS S3 from EMR instance to another EC2 instance directory.

So far I am trying to do it using java SFTP. Also tried to use AWS S3 Client to put object into s3.

**Here is my code:**

```
      try {
            String bucketName  = "my-bucket/product-images";
            BufferedImage image;
            URL url =new URL(product_image_url);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
            String imageName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(product_image_url);

            /*Tried creating new file in current directory*/
            File file = new File(imageName);
            ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",file);
            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,imageName,file));


            /*Here passing source as file name created in current dir
             I have also tried giving bucket path as                 
             sftpChannel.put("s3://xwalker-images/product-images/"+imageName, imageName);
            */

            sftpChannel.put("imageName, "/my_images/"+imageName);
        } catch (SftpException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here I am getting error Nullpointer at `sftpChannel.put` as imageName is getting NULL.

Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?
I have tried this executing on a local machine and it works fine. But when I run it on AWS-EMR it fails.
Is it possible to do what I am expecting in AWS S3?

Comment: Is java necessary ? You can directly use command to copy file from S3 to EC2. Not an expert on AWS but just making a suggestion.

Comment: Yes.. Java is needed cause I am doing it on the fly inside a java map-reduce program